# Calculate data transfer from CloudFront per user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, http-live-streaming

I am using CloudFront to stream(hls) data from s3 bucket want to calculate how many Megabytes of data per user is consuming.

**Whole architecture** -

When a user upload a video from mobile app it runs a lambda function which trigger the MediaConvert function and convert the video into m3u8 extension (hls). For streaming video to user we are using CloudFront though which access m3u8 files from s3 bucket. Now I want to calculate how many MB of data is transfer per user and store it in mongo DB.

PS - we know which videos belongs to which user just want to calculate how many Megabytes transfer has happen for viewing those videos.

Comment: I think you would need to activate [CloudFront access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) to record the traffic. You could then query the logs (eg [using Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html)) to calculate the traffic per file.

Comment: as i know which video belong to which user. Is there any way i can check how many times the video got streamed and how much data transfer occurred ?

Comment: Yes, the access logs will tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to activate [CloudFront access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) to record the traffic.

You can then query the logs (eg [using Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html)) to calculate the traffic per file.